# Excel - sheet names equal to cell (but the cells giving name to the sheets are all in the same sheet)

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I would like to know if it is possible to have the sheet names equal to a specific cell of just one sheet.

For example:

I have a sheet called names

```
A1 = Name1

A2 = Name2

A3 = Name3

A4 = Name4

A5 = Name5
```

So the sheet names should be based on these five values

```
Sheet2 = Name1

Sheet3 = Name2

Sheet4 = Name3

Sheet5 = Name4

Sheet6 = Name5
```

Is this possible with VBA?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could make it event triggered.

**1)** Place the below code in the worksheet object for the "Names" tab.

**2)** Put all the sheet [code names](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm) in the "Names" sheet in the first column (no headers).

**3)** Put the tab names of your choice for the respective sheets in the second column.

The sheet names should change automatically when you change the values in the second column.

**CODE**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim sheetCodeName As String

    If Target.Column = "2" Then
        sheetName = Target.value
        sheetCodeName = Target.Offset(0, -1).value

        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Sheet.CodeName = sheetCodeName Then

                On Error GoTo INVALIDCOLUMNNAME:
                Sheet.name = sheetName
                On Error GoTo 0

            End If

        Next Sheet

    End If

Exit Sub

INVALIDCOLUMNNAME:
msgbox "Invalid Column Name"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets(#).Name = Range("cell location").Value
```

The `#` refers to the sheet index number and the `cell location` is the address of the cell (e.g. `A2` or `E17`)

You are going to want to put some error handling around that however because it will error if you already have a sheet with the same name:

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(#).Name = Range("cell location").Value
If Err.Number > 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Msgbox Range("cell location").Value & " name already exists!"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). Could you please put the full code? I am a beginner in VBA, I will check out how to handle errors as well, thank you for the tip

Comment: @SergeInácio Stack Overflow is a place for code writers to get help with a specific problem.  In generally it is not designed for writing the entire code for a user.  My answer will address your specific problem, but if you are looking for someone to write your code for you, you will probably have to look elsewhere.  I did add a sample error handler for you but as for the rest of the code, you will be on your own to write.

Comment: thanks again :). I won't ask again for a full code, But I still got to figure out how I will get the **Sheets(#).Name = Range("cell location").Value** to work, will accept the answer of course once I did it, thank you.

Comment: Added a little blurb to help you understand my syntax a little better.

Comment: Thank you, this part I understood.. so without the additional error code, this single line of code should do it? Is there no (i.e. Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)) befor and ending?

Comment: Yes you need to put it inside a `Sub` and run the `Sub`.

Comment: Now that is the part I don't know :P. Which sub it is. I programmed with other languages, but this for me is completely different.

Comment: Try using a macro recorder (built in to excel) to record you doing a few simple tasks.  Then you can look at that syntax to get a better idea of how to set a Sub.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your tips and help, I appriciate that :), but the other answer solved my problem, that is why I have accepted the other one.